# Error watching file for changes: EMFILE {"code":"EMFILE","errno":"EMFILE","syscall":"Error watching file for changes:","filename": null}?

Tags: ios, facebook, reactjs, mobile, react-native-ios

Error watching file for changes:

> EMFILE {"code":"EMFILE","errno":"EMFILE","syscall":"Error watching
>   file for changes:","filename": null}?

```
  "dependencies": {
        "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
        "react-native": "0.47.1",
        "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.16",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
        "redux": "^3.7.2",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
      }
```

Comment: getting the same error: " Error watching file for changes: EMFILE
{"code":"EMFILE","errno":"EMFILE","syscall":"Error watching file for changes:","filename":null}
Error: Error watching file for changes: EMFILE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1374:11)"

Answer (score 7):

You need to install `watchman` through brew:

```
brew install watchman
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the error as `Error watching file for changes: EMFILE`

Run these commands to resolve this problem:

1. brew uninstall --force watchman
2. brew link automake
3. brew install --HEAD watchman